# SQL Server : split column into table in a trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
UserID  Email
-----------------------------------
1       1_0@email.com;1_1@email.com
2       2_0@email.com;2_1@email.com
3       3_0@email.com;3_3@email.com
```

And I need to create a temp table that will look like this:

```
UserID  Email
-----------------------------------
1       1_0@email.com
1       1_1@email.com
2       2_0@email.com
2       2_1@email.com
3       3_0@email.com
3       3_1@email.com
```

The temp table will be used in a update trigger and I was wondering if there is a more elegant approach than doing something like this:

```
-- Create temp table to hold the result table
CREATE TABLE #resultTable(
   UserID int,
   Email  nvarchar(50)
)

-- Create temp table to help iterate through table
CREATE TABLE #tempTable(
   ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
   UserID int,
   Email  nvarchar(50)
)

-- Insert data from updated table into temp table
INSERT INTO #tempTable
   SELECT [UserId], [Email] 
   FROM inserted

-- Iterate through temp table
DECLARE @count int = @@ROWCOUNT
DECLARE @index int = 1

WHILE (@index <= @count)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @userID int
    DECLARE @email nvarchar(50)

    -- Get the user ID and email values
    SELECT 
        @userID = [UserID], @email = [Email]
    FROM #tempTable
    WHERE [ID] = @index

    -- Insert the parsed email address into the result table
    INSERT INTO #resultTable([UserID], [Email])
       SELECT @userID, [Data]
       FROM myFunctionThatSplitsAColumnIntoATable(@email, ';')

    SET @index = @index + 1
END

-- Do stuff with the result table
```

Comment: By far the best approach would be to get your main table normalized. Allowing multiple values in a single column is a pita to work with and violates 1NF. Here is a great article about splitting strings. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd better avoid iterative approaches when using **T-SQL** *unless strictly necessary*, specially inside triggers.

You can use the [APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator.

From **MSDN**:

> The APPLY operator allows you to invoke a table-valued function for each row returned by an outer table expression of a query.

So, you can try to replace all your code with this:

```
INSERT INTO #resultTable(UserID, Email)
SELECT T1.UserID
      ,T2.Data
FROM updated T1
CROSS APPLY myFunctionThatSplitsAColumnIntoATable(T1.Email, ';') AS T2
```